# Issues in migrating Google Cloud Project to Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-console-developer

I have projects available in google cloud which i want to import on firebase. On firebase console, none of the project got listed in dropdown of adding project. On further investigation, I got to know that a google's below API is getting crashed.

https://mobilesdk-pa.clients6.google.com/v1/projects:listMigratable?key=

Status Code: 500

I have filed a ticket on firebase support as well. Meanwhile, can anyone have a workaround or any solution to help me in proceeding forward?

Comment: I don't see any workaround that you could do. Specially with the service itself (*as you mentioned*) is having an issue.

Comment: This question is pretty vague. A Google Cloud Project could be a number of different things and Firebase is a collection of different services and API's - Cloud Firestore, Storage, Firebase Realtime Database etc. Can you be a bit more specific in what you're asking and what the expected result would be?

Comment: I wanted to shift on fcm service as google is going to end it's support to gcm soon. For migration, i need to import google console project to firebase console, so that project id remains same. The app is already live and using gcm service for pushes.

Comment: That sounds more like a services question than a coding question. You should reach out to Firebase support direction for guidance.